# Running search and replace for only certain values using bash shell

Tags: bash, search, replace

I’m using bash and wondering if there is a way to do a search and replace with given conditions.  I have a CSV file with rows resembling the following …

```
Ira,Frances,Lancaster,373611,06211101,239661,239661,8,8/16/01
```

If the 6th and 7th columns contain the same values, I would like to replace the 7th column with an empty string, so the above would become

```
Ira,Frances,Lancaster,373611,06211101,239661,,8,8/16/01
```

I’m using Mac 10.9.5 with bash shell.  What is the shortest way to edit the file to remove the data I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$6 == $7 {$7=""} 1' file.csv
```

**Testing:**

```
s='Ira,Frances,Lancaster,373611,06211101,239661,239661,8,8/16/01'
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$6 == $7 {$7=""} 1' <<< "$s"
Ira,Frances,Lancaster,373611,06211101,239661,,8,8/16/01
```

Comment: Thanks.  This command seems to work but it removes all the commas from my file.  Anywya I can preserve the commas and just remove the values I dont want?

Comment: I just updated to preserve comma and provided a test code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution :

```
awk -F,'{if  ($6 ==  $7) {$7 =""; print $0} }' file.csv
```